# How to automatize the making and sending of event's attendance certificates?

Tags: conference, attendance, certification

Our department make a lot of attendance certificates, for events we run, and we waste a lot of work typing attendance lists and sending them by email. Most of the public are students are from my institution, and we can get a list of names and email address. We make about 1.500 certificates by year.

We are thinking about using a event system, but I'm having trouble to find one that makes certificates and don't cost thousand of dollars.

Anyone have a suggestion? A better solution?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's really about academia, as stated in the FAQ, and it is also a shopping question which is also explicitly called out as off topic in the faq.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe I can edit to make less "shopping question". As making attendance certificates is a part of many events, like conferences, I assumed the question to be on topic.

Comment: But it still doesn't really fit the topics as listed https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Managing symposiums/congresses/conferences/courses is a central part of the "Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor".

Comment: (Changed the mysterious "os" to "of" in the title...)

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for a mail merge or even vba macro... could try looking on stack overflow for examples...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would fit better at software recommendations.

Comment: So you basically want a program that'll print off a certificate for each person in a list of 1,500 names?  Or would you prefer to email the certificates?  Or, what precisely would you like the system to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested in my comment that you could search on Stack Overflow for a mailmerge or vba solution.

This is one example of printing sheets that you could adapt to your situation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46332953/4961700